# How to provide an `InjectionToken` that has its own `factory`?

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

Consider the following `InjectionToken` for the type `Foo`:

```
export const FOO = new InjectionToken<Foo>(
  'foo token',
  { factory: () => new Foo() });
```

Now assume I was crazy enough to aim for 100% test coverage. To that end I'd have to unit test that little `factory` function.

I was thinking to create an injector that has just one provider in my test:

```
const inj = Injector.create({
  providers: [{ provide: FOO }] // compiler error here
});

const foo = inj.get(FOO);

expect(foo).toBeTruthy();
```

Unfortunately this fails with a compiler error, because `{ provide: FOO }` is not a valid provider without a `useValue`, `useFactory`, or `useExisting` property. But why am I forced to define one of them when the injection token comes with its own factory?

Of course I tried all options nonetheless:

- `useValue: FOO` compiles and runs, but doesn't seem to execute the factory method
- `useFactory: () => FOO, deps: []` also compiles and runs, but doesn't seem to execute the factory method either
- `useExisting: FOO` compiles, but fails with a circular dependency error during runtime

Funny enough, a similar scenario is presented in [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#tree-shakable-injectiontoken) for `InjectionToken`, but it doesn't show the registration I'm looking for:

```
const MY_SERVICE_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<MyService>('Manually constructed MyService', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => new MyService(inject(MyDep)),
});

// How is `MY_SERVICE_TOKEN` token provided?

const instance = injector.get(MY_SERVICE_TOKEN);
```

I created an [example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-py8wbd) so you can try yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `factory` function for the `InjectionToken`, the token is automatically provided in root. Therefore you don't need to provide it in the test bed either.

In order to use this feature in test, you need to use `TestBed` instead of just `Injector.create`.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('Foo', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({}));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: Foo = TestBed.get(FOO);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

[The docs](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#description) say

> When creating an `InjectionToken`, you can optionally specify a
>   factory function which returns (possibly by creating) a default value
>   of the parameterized type `T`. This sets up the `InjectionToken` using
>   this factory as a provider as if it was defined explicitly in the
>   application's root injector. If the factory function, which takes zero
>   arguments, needs to inject dependencies, it can do so using the
>   `inject` function. See below for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't work. The error is `StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken foo token]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken foo token!`. See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-py8wbd (check the file `app.component.ts`).

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Updated answer. You need to use `TestBed` instead of `Injector`.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that the following works:

```
class Example {}

export const EXP = new InjectionToken<Example>(
  'EXP',
  {
    factory: (): Example => new Example(),
    providedIn: 'root',
  },
);

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SomeService {
  constructor(@Inject(EXP) private readonly exp: Example) {}
}

  // @ts-expect-error StaticProvider type is missing a union for InjectionToken with factories 
  const injector = Injector.create({
    providers: [
      { provide: EXP },
      { provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeService, deps: [ EXP ] },
    ],
  });

  const theService = injector.get(SomeService);
```

But you have to silence the compiler error because the types in Angular are missing `InjectionToken` for the [StaticProvider](https://angular.io/api/core/StaticProvider).

Alternatively you can do:

```
  const injector = Injector.create({
    providers: [
      [ { provide: EXP } ],
      { provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeService, deps: [ EXP ] },
    ],
  });
```

and take advantage of the `any[]` in that type to avoid the `// @ts-expect-error`.

It was pointed out to me that the [full code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/examples/core/di/ts/injector_spec.ts) for that example in the documentation is the spec file unit test. However it uses a magic `MockRootScopeInjector` which doesn't seem like production worthy code.

Comment: This is for Angular v14, which is rather old. But I think it will apply to Angular v15 also.